# fscanf not scan line after whitespace

Tags: c, scanf

### I have a problem with the fscanf function

Excuse my bad english.

The program reads the file as follows:

```
status = fscanf(ifile, "%%!%11s", ifbuf);
```

if the file starts directly with the desired entry, eg

```
%! UTF-8
some text
```

`fscanf` reads a line in `ifbuf`.
If in the line starts with whitespaces

```
    %! UTF-8
some text
```

`fscanf` does not read anything.

Making the `fscanf` function work in both cases can be done by adding a space in the format string:

```
status = fscanf(ifile, " %%!%11s", ifbuf);
```

---

I wanted to know how correct the behavior of the `fscanf` function is.

Comment: Did you carefully read the specification and documentation of `fscanf` ? Read it several times!

Comment: fscanf should skip leading spaces, is not it?

Comment: No it should be able to read any characters, spaces included. By the way, fscanf is a core function and you can be very confident it works as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe as the observed behaviour is the correct behaviour. The [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) functions only skip leading white space on some (most — all but `%c` and `%[`, in fact) conversion specifications. For literal components of the format string, it behaves more or less literally, except that a space in the format string matches any number of white space characters in the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `s` in your format string, which matches a sequence of bytes that are not white-space characters. The function reads bytes, interprets them according to a format, and stores the results in its arguments.

In your case it find a line starting with spaces, which doesn't match the format you are looking for.